# Interactive testing using

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I have been working with testing framework **mocha** and assertion library **chai** for the past few days. Is there any possible way to make an interactive testing , like passing inputs to test in CLI when the test is running ?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about why you want this? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any direct support by mocha for input, but you can get around this by using [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env), which gives access to the user environment, with [`env`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103474) or [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), depending on what OS you're running on.

```
# Unix
env SOME_INPUT=something secretKey=magic mocha test

# Windows
set SOME_INPUT=something
set secretKey=magic
mocha test
```

Then in your test:

```
var input = process.env.SOME_INPUT; // "something"
var key = process.env.secretKey; // "magic"
```